# Etsy.com type site CMS - wordpress or drupal?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

Ok, so I want to build a site similar to Etsy.com that will allow users to create accounts and post their items for sale.

Typically I build from scratch, but I was wondering if there might be a good Wordpress plugin or Drupal mod that might be better for me to use rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Any ideas?  if you have drupal suggestions please list any helpful mods or helpful wordpress plugins... or if you have another CMS you prefer that would be nice as well.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarketPress, if you're trying to leverage Wordpress might be a good start. It ties in Wordpress with BuddyPress (multi-user) with MultiSite.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce/

Comment: that MarketPress is very impressive... but I was hoping for something open source and free....  this will not really be a money generating site... at least not a lot of money.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to look for more "open source" solutions. For the money, it seems to be worth the plugins and setup needed to fulfill the functionality you want (member-to-member relations, create and verify accounts, post products, etc.)

Comment: @dominic... yes I agree that sometimes it's definitely worth the money, but this site will be more of a trial and error so I don't believe it will earn any noticeable revenue... hence, the cheaper the better for now.